# Proper use of encryption in CyanogenMod 13?

Tags: cyanogenmod, security, nexus-5

I'm running CM13 on Nexus 5 and I want to know what the best practices are for encryption.

- It appears that encryption was [enabled by default](https://tretkowski.de/2015/12/23/cm13-disk-encryption/) when I installed CM13 early this year, but I don't know how to verify if that's the case.
- Many guides use a command-line tool called `vdc` but I can't find documentation on that tool (even `man vdc` doesn't work in the shell).
- The android docs say that the [encryption password is set by default](https://source.android.com/security/encryption/full-disk.html) to `default_password` and many forum posts note that this is the case on CM13 as well.

How do I ensure that my CM13 is encrypted and make sure that it has a strong password?